# Is it possible to change display settings and apply without logging out like Windows?

Tags: settings, external-monitor, projector

When I want to connect a second monitor or projector to my computer, I always have to change display settins, like seperate x screens configuration, and save and logout to apply new settings. It is really anoying. For example, if I configure my display settings for only use external monitor and save it and then unplug the external monitor, Ubuntu does not understand that I unpluged it and it is continues to send display to external monitor. So in order to change my display setting I have to plugin external monitor again.
Is there a work around for this problem?

Comment: windows doesn't require you to log out to change display settings.

Comment: @MikeBrown: That's what he's saying in the question.

Comment: @GeorgeEdison, I know, I was joking around. The question could be interpreted as saying "without logging out like Windows (requires you to do)"

Answer (score 1):

Anything that modifies `xorg.conf` requires the X server to be restarted before the changes can be applied. This is a limitation of the X server.

*However,* depending on your video card, you may be able to work around this issue by using one of your video card manufacturer's utilities. Nvidia, for example, ships a GUI configuration tool with its driver that allows you to add, remove, and modify the geometry of displays without restarting the X server (the tool also provides the option of permanently saving the changes to `xorg.conf` but that's not what you're asking). These tools cannot, however, add or remove *X displays* since that capability is reserved for the X server itself.

Something to consider down the road: X is eventually being replaced by [Wayland](http://wayland.freedesktop.org/) which will (hopefully) be much easier to configure than X and offer the ability to add or remove displays while running.